# How to fix foreign key constraint when trying to references two primary keys from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Misson:

I'm trying to create two tables in MySQL, the first table has two primary keys (composite). The second table has three, two of which are foreign keys that reference the first tables two primary keys. So now I'm trying to bridge them, which isolates the problem code and can be seen below.

Issue:

MySQL workbench refuses allow me to create a table that references another table's two primary keys. It just gives me the error code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

I tried:

Changing the attribute types from datetime to varchar(). Changing the attribute names. Checked spelling 5 times. Referencing only one key works fine, but I need both.

Problem Code (SQL Table):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestInformation2
(
WorkOrder varchar(15),                              
Date datetime,                                  
TechnicianID smallint,
Primary key (WorkOrder, Date)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestBridge2
(
TestBridgeID integer Primary key,
WorkOrder varchar(15),      
Date datetime,                  
Foreign key (WorkOrder) references TestInformation (WorkOrder),
Foreign key (Date) references TestInformation (Date)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Result I want:

Create the table 'TestBridge' which has the two foreign key attributes: WorkOrder and Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One single foreign key has to be created for this like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestBridge2
(
TestBridgeID integer Primary key,
WorkOrder varchar(15),      
Date datetime,                  

Foreign key (WorkOrder, Date) references TestInformation2 (WorkOrder, Date)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be one composite foreign key, not two:

```
CREATE TABLE `TestBridge2` (
    `TestBridgeID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `WorkOrder` VARCHAR(15),
    `Date` DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (`TestBridgeID`),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`WorkOrder`, `Date`) REFERENCES `TestInformation2` (`WorkOrder`, `Date`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks this works, could you explain why this is necessary to do it this way? Also what does CONSTRAINT do in this example?

Comment: FK must refer to PK and your PK is composite so the FK must be composite as well. The syntax is up to manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html. I have not keyed in the command manually (it's easier to make typo mistake), I created tables with your commands then used my SQL client (HeidiSQL) to create the FK and then copy/pasted the create table command here with tiny adjustments.